# Skill creation in a python text based RPG

Tags: python, oop

I am in the process of creating a text-based RPG for the purpose of learning more about OOP in Python. Right now things are going well, but I'm facing a problem that I don't exactly can find a good answer: Skill implementation. I also think that I'm going to face similar problem with the Items.

At this moment I have 3 classes(professions): `Fighter`, `Rogue`, and `Mage`. Each of these classes should have their own skills, but, skills have similar things(name, description, MP usage), so I created a `BasicSkill` class, and 3 subclasses: `PassiveSkill`, `ActiveSkill` and `ChanelledSkill`.

Explaining: `PassiveSkill` are skills that doesn't require MP to use, are always active, and in most of cases, give the player buffs, like dual-wielding, more resistance, etc. `ActiveSkill` are skills that require MP to be used, and, in majority, cause damage or a instant buff. Finally, `ChanelledSkill` are skills that require more than one turn to be used, cost more MP than the others, and can be interrupted

But, when comes to the skill creation, I can only think in something like this:

```
def hack_and_slash(self):
        """This is a Fighter skill, it's melee and has no cool down."""
        from skills import ActiveSkill
        hack_and_slash = ActiveSkill("Hack n' Slash", "A powerful double attack that has a chance of causing bleeding.",
                                     8, 3)
        self.mp -= hack_and_slash.
        # more about the skill goes here, like what it does in terms of damaging, buffing, etc.
```

Which I think is not exactly what I'm aiming for, since I have to instantiate it every time I use, or something in the same lines.

I want to create the skills in a way that would require less instantiation, and also make more possible to cast. Also, all characters(player, npc, and enemies) can cast skills.

There's a bunch of files in this project, so I will post the ones I think are more relevant here, and, if you want, you can check out the project [here](https://github.com/deadpyxel/D-py-D).

This is my `Player` class:

```
from character import Character


# TODO implementation of player basic attacks and abilities
# TODO implementation of a D&D style skill system(diplomacy, stealth, streetwise, etc)

class Player(Character):
    LEVEL_UP = 100  # initial XP to lvl up
    COMMANDS = {'attack': 'a', 'character': 'c', 'inventory': 'i'}  # commands available for the player
    # in future this skills will be used inside and outside combat situations, for like take out an enemy in stealth,
    # or convince a guard to let you in a closed door
    SKILLS = {'persuasion': 0, 'intimidation': 0, 'stealth': 0, 'perception': 0}
    DAILY_SELF_HEALS = 4  # each ingame day player can use 4 self heals, it resets after getting the rested status
    ATTRIBUTES = {'strenght': 0, 'constitution': 0, 'dexterity': 0, 'intelligence': 0, 'wisdom': 0, 'charisma': 0}

    def __init__(self, armor_class):
        super().__init__(input("Tell us your name, hero:\n>"), 20, 10, {'gold': 10, 'torch': 1}, armor_class, 1)
        self.exp = 0
        self.max_hp = self.hp  # max HP of the player
        self.max_mp = self.mp  # max MP of the player
        self._strength = 0  # should I change it to dictionary with the attributes instead?
        self._constitution = 0
        self._dexterity = 0
        self._intelligence = 0
        self._wisdom = 0
        self._charisma = 0

    def level_up(self):
        if self.exp >= self.LEVEL_UP:
            self.lvl += 1
            self.LEVEL_UP *= 1.25
            self.LEVEL_UP = int(self.LEVEL_UP)
            self.exp = 0
            stat_choice = input(
                "You have 2 points to spend in your attributes!\nType which attributes you want to raise up: ")
            stat_choice = stat_choice.split(',')
            self.ATTRIBUTES[stat_choice[0]] += 1
            self.ATTRIBUTES[stat_choice[1]] += 1
            self.max_hp = int(self.max_hp * 1.1)
            self.max_mp = int(self.max_mp * 1.1)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def gain_exp(self, exp):
        self.exp += exp
        print("You gained %d XP" % exp)
        if self.level_up():
            print("Congratulations, you gained a level!\nYour current level is %d\n" % self.lvl)
        else:
            print("Your current XP is %d/%d\n" % (self.exp, self.LEVEL_UP))

    def get_loot(self, enemy):
        # buggy right now, problem with remove inventory from dead enemy
        for item in enemy.inventory:
            while True:
                get_item = input("You found %s! do you want to get it?(Y=yes/N=no/A=all items)" % item)
                if get_item.lower() == "a":
                    self.inventory.update(enemy.inventory)
                    enemy.inventory = {}
                    return
                elif get_item.lower() == "y":
                    self.inventory[item] = enemy.inventory[item]
                    enemy.inventory.pop(item, None)
                    break
                elif get_item.lower() == "n":
                    break
                else:
                    print("Unfortunately, you don't have this choice hero, take a look again...")

    def combat(self, enemy):
        """
        the combat between two entities(player and enemy)
        :param enemy: the enemy of current character
        :return:
        """
        if super().combat(enemy):
            self.gain_exp(10)
            self.get_loot(enemy)
        else:
            print("\t\t[GAME OVER...]\t\t")

    def self_heal(self):
        if self.DAILY_SELF_HEALS > 0:
            self.DAILY_SELF_HEALS -= 1
            self.hp += int(self.max_hp / 4)

    def rest(self):
        rest_time = input("\tHow much time would you like to rest? ")
        if rest_time >= 6:
            self.STATUS['rested'] = True

    def __str__(self):
        str_info = "\tName: [%s]\tLEVEL: %d\n\tHP: %2d\t\tMP: %2d" % (self.name, self.lvl, self.hp, self.mp)
        str_stats = "\t\tSTR: %2d\n\t\tCON: %2d\n\t\tDEX: %2d\n\t\tINT: %2d\n\t\tWIS: %2d\n\t\tCHA: %2d\n" % (
            self._strength, self._constitution, self._dexterity, self._intelligence, self._wisdom,
            self._charisma)
        return "|%s|\n%s" % (str_info, str_stats)
```

This, my `Character` class:

```
# all character, being Player, NPC, or Enemy content should be implemented here
from utils import Dice


    class Character:
        """
        Main character class, all living entities derivate from it
        """

        # a dictionary of possible status of player, the idea is that this status change gameplay/combat in the future.
        # By default all characters are rested.
        STATUS = {'rested': True, 'hunger': False, 'poisoned': False, 'bleeding': False, 'blind': False, 'frozen': False,
                  'paralyzed': False, 'dead': False}
        # Right now there are only four equipment slot, which one should receive an armor object, not yet implemented
        EQUIPMENT_SLOTS = {'head': None, 'chest': None, 'legs': None, 'boots': None}

        def __init__(self, name, hp, mp, inventory, armor_class, lvl):
            """
            Constructor for a character
            :param name: name for the character
            :type name: str
            :param hp: hit points(health) for the character
            :type hp: int
            :param mp: magic points(mana) for the character
            :type mp: int
            :param inventory: inventory of character(gold, items, equips)
            :type inventory: dict
            :param armor_class: main defense
            :type armor_class: int
            :param lvl: level of character
            :type lvl: int
            :return: Character object
            """
            self.name = name
            self.hp = hp
            self.mp = mp
            self.inventory = inventory
            self.armor_class = armor_class
            self.lvl = lvl
            self.atk_bonus = 1
            self.atk_dmg = 4
            self.movement_speed = 6

        def take_dmg(self, dmg):
            self.hp -= dmg
            if self.hp <= 0:
                print("\n[%s has died!]" % self.name)
                self.STATUS['dead'] = True
            else:
                print("\n[%s has %d health left" % (self.name, self.hp))

        def attack(self, enemy):
            """
            All characters can attack, so this is the main attack(physical) method
            :param enemy: Enemy that is in combat with character
            :return:
            """
            d20 = Dice(20)
            dmg = self.atk_dmg
            if d20.roll() + self.atk_bonus >= enemy.armor_class:
                if d20 == 20:
                    print("CRITICAL HIT!")
                    dmg *= 2
                else:
                    dice_dmg = Dice(self.atk_dmg)
                    dmg = dice_dmg.roll()
                print("\n[%s hit %s for %d damage]" % (self.name, enemy.name, dmg))
                enemy.take_dmg(dmg)
                if enemy.STATUS['dead']:
                    return
            else:
                print("\n[%s missed]" % self.name)

        def combat(self, enemy):
            while True:
                self.attack(enemy)
                if enemy.STATUS['dead']:
                    return True
                enemy.attack(self)
                if self.STATUS['dead']:
                    break
            return False

        def equip_armor(self, armor_piece):
            """
            Equip a piece of armor in the correspondent slot
            :param armor_piece: armor piece to equip
            :type armor_piece: object
            :return:
            """
            replace_equip = input(
                "Would you like to replace %s with %s?(Y/N)" % (self.EQUIPMENT_SLOTS['head'], armor_piece.name))
            if replace_equip.lower() == "y":
                self.EQUIPMENT_SLOTS['head'] = armor_piece
                return
            else:
                return

        def list_inventory(self):
            """
            list a character's inventory
            :return:
            """
            print("\t\t[%s] INVENTORY:\t\t\n" % self.name)
            for item in self.inventory:
                print("%s:\t%d" % (item, self.inventory[item]))
```

The `Skill` class:

```
# All basic skill implementation should be here


    class BasicSkill:
        SKILL_TYPE = {'passive': False, 'active': False, 'channeled': False}

        def __init__(self, name, description, skill_type, skill_dmg=0, skill_range=0):
            """
            Basic Skill class
            :param name: skill name
            :type name: string
            :param description: description
            :type description: string
            :param skill_type: passive, active or channeled
            :type skill_type: string
            :param skill_dmg: default=0, meaning it's passive
            :type skill_dmg: int
            :param skill_range: default=0, meaning it's personal
            :type skill_range: int
            :return:
            """
            self._name = name
            self._description = description
            self.SKILL_TYPE[skill_type] = True
            self.skill_dmg = skill_dmg
            self.skill_range = skill_range


    class PassiveSkill(BasicSkill):
        def __init__(self, name, description, skill_type='passive'):
            super().__init__(name, description, skill_type)


    class ActiveSkill(BasicSkill):
        def __init__(self, name, description, skill_dmg, mp_use, cooldown=1, skill_type='active', skill_range=1):
            super().__init__(name, description, skill_type, skill_dmg, skill_range)
            self.mp_use = mp_use
            self.cooldown = cooldown


    class ChanneledSkill(BasicSkill):
        def __init__(self, name, description, skill_dmg, channeling_time, cooldown=2, skill_type='chanelled',
                     skill_range=1):
            super().__init__(name, description, skill_type, skill_dmg, skill_range)
            self.channeling_time = channeling_time
            self.cooldown = cooldown
```

and, as example, the `Fighter` class, all the classes/professions are implemented in similar way:

```
from player import Player


# TODO implement fighter stats and attacks

class Fighter(Player):
    """
    Fighter class, a strong warrior that uses meele attacks to face his opponents
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(armor_class=10)
        print("\nYou have chosen the path of strength!")
        self._strength += 2
        self._constitution += 2
        self.atk_bonus += 1
        self.atk_dmg += 3

    def hack_and_slash(self):
        from skills import ActiveSkill
        hack_and_slash = ActiveSkill("Hack n' Slash", "A powerful double attack that has a chance of causing bleeding.",
                                     8, 3)
        self.mp -= hack_and_slash.mp_use

    def __str__(self):
        super().__str__()
```

Any ideas are welcome, as well as code improvement tips. I tried to figure out a good way to make this skill implementation system, but I couldn't exactly find one. The only alternative I tough was a dictionary of skills, but I don't know how would it work. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Oh, thanks @TheEspinosa, I didn't knew of codereview. I posted it there.

Comment: Couldn't you just... put the skills on the character object, representing "this character knows this skill?"